# C# VS 2013 Error 02019: Invalid target type for /target: must specify 'exe', 'winexe', 'library', 'module', 'appcontainerexe' or 'winmdobj' CSC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, csproj, sqlproj

I work on a website that uses various class libraries that are occasionally updated. One of the libraries is a sqlproj file and I believe it was made with VS2010. It is a dependency for other libraries and I'm not able to build/rebuild my solution because I keep getting this error, thus the DLLs will not generate. When I first open the project in VS2013, I get a migration report that opens in my browser. But the migration states that it's successful. When I try building the project, I get the error:

> Error 1   02019: Invalid target type for /target: must specify 'exe', 'winexe', 'library', 'module', 'appcontainerexe' or 'winmdobj'  CSC

I've tried to follow some of the recommendations on this question with essentially the same issue, but have been unsuccessful. [Project fails to load due to missing SqlServer.targets file after upgrading to Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006482/project-fails-to-load-due-to-missing-sqlserver-targets-file-after-upgrading-to-v) It seems like there are some unresolved streams in that question as well.

Any help would be great. Happy to provide more details and/or edit the question to make it more generalized. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While none of the answers in [Project fails to load due to missing SqlServer.targets file after upgrading to Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20006482/project-fails-to-load-due-to-missing-sqlserver-targets-file-after-upgrading-to-v) worked for me, and nobody else had ideas here on Stack Overflow, it turns out this was a bug related to backwards compatibility in Visual Studio 2013 and SSDTs (SQL Server Developer Tools). A comment in this forum solved my issue:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedbackdetail/view/979839

> Posted by bsclifton on 11/15/2014 at 7:18 AM
>
> Had this issue too with the Community 2013 edition; Going to Tools->Extensions and Updates and updating "Microsoft SQL Server Update for database tooling" resolved the issue :)

Answer (score 1):

Changed .sqlproj file with following as per the advised on other stack workflow thread. Worked for me.

$(MSBuildToolsPath)  to $(MSBuildBinPath) in import tag

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message but on VS2017 in .sqlproj.
It helped to add DefaultTargets argument in .targets file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="SetDacVersionToAssemblyVersion" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />

  <Target Name="SetDacVersionToAssemblyVersion" AfterTargets="CoreCompile" Condition=" '$(EnableDacVersionFromAssembly)' == 'True' ">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(IntermediateTargetFullFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" PropertyName="IntermediateTargetAssembly" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <DacVersion>$(IntermediateTargetAssembly.Split(',')[1].Split('=')[1])</DacVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>

</Project>
```